# How to determine program causing "banned" icon to appear in the system tray?

Tags: apt, package-management, xfce, system-tray

This has been modified so as to not duplicate.  Please remove that status or provide a link the the duplicate.

When one sees this "banned" icon in the system tray:

[image: system tray screenshot]

How does one determine which program's icon failed to load?  Hovering over it fails to do so.  Clicking on it drops down a blank area.

Comment: it misses its icon, that's all :)

Comment: How do you remove it? What exactly you mean by screw up?

Comment: it's a process that can't find its indicator icon (or (I believe) got messed up by a race condition). In Xfce that could be Dropbox I know (in which case you could fix it by doing `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`

Comment: This icon typically appears if there's a package management issue. Could you please open a terminal, type and run the command `sudo apt-get install -f` and [edit] your question to include its output? Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)). Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why the drop-down menu appears empty though.

Comment: `# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Zanna's solution `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start` worked.  How can I prevent the race condition?  How could I have looked up the meaning of the "banned" icon?  Is there an xfce4 document somewhere that tells about stuff like this?  Also, when "mystery" icons appear that don't say anything when you hover over them, where does one look in the system for what they are?  Should that be a new question for the community?

Comment: If it's dropbox, then this question is a duplicate. The icon is just the one that is displayed if the real icon for any program could not be loaded